# Can I use a apex:repeat on a VF page to iterate through related external data? Trying to test in dev org using Odata standard system

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, externalid, lightning-connect

Object type not accessible. 
Please check permissions and make sure the object is not in development mode:

An error occurred while connecting to the external system. Please try again, or contact your administrator about this error. Attempted to reach this URL:https:xyz.com?$filter=EmployeeID.......

When working on External object and external sources

We have created a VF page in which  apex:repeat on a VF page to iterate through related external data

Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the external objects just like a custom object. Here is an example using the repeat tag on the sample external object from the trailhead [project](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/project/quickstart-lightning-connect):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:detail relatedList="false"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Orders__r}" var="order">
        <apex:outputField value="{!order.orderID__c}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```